# Custom share on Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to make custom share (Image with text) on Twitter without composeview in ios(Swift). Which Api need to use for post? (Eg: Instagram share for facebook, twitter). 
Gratitude for your Help! Thanks

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/nst/STTwitter But keep in mind that redoing the whole thing is hard, if you're just starting maybe you should go with the default already implemented approach.